# OOP Best practices: Is there any reason to separate out Factory functionality from an abstract base class?

Tags: object-oriented, python-3.x, abstract-class, factory

Consider the following python3 code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Food(ABC):
    _food_factory_map = {}
    _recipes = {}

    @classmethod
    def getFood(cls, foodName):
        return cls._food_factory_map[foodName]()

    @classmethod
    def registerFood(cls, foodName, recipe):
        def callable(foodClass):
            cls._food_factory_map[foodName] = foodClass
            cls._recipes[foodName] = recipe
            return foodClass
        return callable

    def __init__(self):
        print("Starting Food prep")

    @abstractmethod
    def prepareFood(self):
        ...

    def serveFood(self):
        food = self.prepareFood()
        print(food)

@Food.registerFood('Burger', 'Burger Recipe')
class Burger(Food):
    def prepareFood(self):
        return 'Burger is ready!'

@Food.registerFood('Pizza', 'Pizza Recipe')
class Pizza(Food):
    def prepareFood(self):
        return 'Pizza is ready!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fs = ('Burger', 'Pizza')
    for f in fs:
        print(f"Food Recipe: {Food._recipes[f]}")
        food = Food.getFood(f)
        food.serveFood()
```

Here the abstract base class Food has class methods that implement the Factory design pattern. A client can register their own concrete classes with registerFood and retrieve them with getFood. The abstract base class also implements other abstract and concrete methods to define the interface.

One can also separate out the two class methods (getFood and registerFood) and the two class members (_food_factory_map and _recipes) into a class of it's own (FoodFactory)

```
class FoodFactory(ABC):
    _food_factory_map = {}
    _recipes = {}

    @classmethod
    def getFood(cls, foodName):
        return cls._food_factory_map[foodName]()

    @classmethod
    def registerFood(cls, foodName, recipe):
        def callable(foodClass):
            cls._food_factory_map[foodName] = foodClass
            cls._recipes[foodName] = recipe
            return foodClass
        return callable
```

All the client code will then change to using FoodFactory instead of Food.

```
@FoodFactory.registerFood('Pizza', 'Pizza Recipe')
class Pizza(Food):
    def prepareFood(self):
        return 'Pizza is ready!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fs = ('Burger', 'Pizza')
    for f in fs:
        print(f"Food Recipe: {FoodFactory._recipes[f]}")
        food = FoodFactory.getFood(f)
        food.serveFood()
```

Which of these implementations is better and why? Or is it perfectly reasonable to use either? Is it language dependent?

One advantage I can think off is that with the second method, one can override the __new__ of FoodFactory to directly return an instance of the appropriate food rather than calling a separate getFood method. But that difference seems largely cosmetic.

Answer (score 4):

### Your blanket question

> OOP Best practices: Is there any reason to separate out Factory functionality from an abstract base class?

A factory is warranted when a constructor is no longer the appropriate solution to the problem at hand. So you could argue that a constructor is a really simple factory, and that you only need to consider a factory (i.e. the separate class) when the construction logic gets complicated enough to warrant separation from the factory's product (i.e. the original class).

So, to answer your blanket question if there is any reason to every separate it out, the answer is yes. Specifically, in cases where the construction logic is sufficiently complex to warrant it, or e.g. when you need an injectable dependency which is able to generate products on the fly.

---

### Your concrete example

It doesn't make semantical sense for `Food` to know a collection of recipes. That's meta-knowledge. Analogously, your car does not contain its own construction blueprint, let alone that of many other cars was well.

My intuition is telling me that this is a composition-over-inheritance violation. It makes more sense for the collection of recipes to live in a dedicated class (let's call it `RecipeBook`).

Inheritance is the wrong construct to use here. You're not making any use of the polymorphism that inheritance provides. A Burger is not a collection of recipes, and that's what your inheritance is currently claiming.

*I'm no Python dev, so I don't feel comfortable writing an improved version of your snippet.*

Comment: I think you've missed the question. A constructor isn't a factory. a factory class creates objects without the caller knowing the exact class. Are you thinking of a 'builder'?

Comment: @Ewan: I think you've missed what I was pointing out. your comment uses "factory" as the strict definition of a particular pattern. I use the word factory more broadly as "something that generates a [product]", which is a spectrum where you can find a constructor on the simple end and "the factory pattern" (in its many shapes) on the other end. The factory pattern supplants the constructor, i.e. it exists because the usual constructor approach is not the right fit, and my answer points out that these are different approach to a similar goal and that context defines what it appropriate.

Comment: @Ewan: I also disagree with your definition of a factory. There are different kinds of factories. Some factories return a base type and have a consumer unaware of the derived concrete type that is being used; you are correct about that. However, there are also other factories where the returning type _is_ known to the consumer, and the factory's expertise is not in choosing between available subtypes, but rather its ability to perform the difficult construction of the (known) type. Both are factories, but only one would apply to your (IMO overly restrictive) definition.

Comment: which of those two definitions is the OP using in their question?

Comment: your "broader definition" is normally called a builder

Comment: @Ewan [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757743/what-is-the-difference-between-builder-design-pattern-and-factory-design-pattern) A builder is a _step by step_ process with an intermediate composite that eventually gets built. A factory is a single-step construction process. An _abstract_ factory is a particular type of factory where the concrete type is hidden from the consumer. What you call "builder vs factory" is in fact "factory vs abstract factory", and builders are something different (but in the same family of "complex construction" patterns)

Comment: quote from the refernced source in the answer to the question you reference "factory method pattern is a creational pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created" My point is though that the OP has implemented this kind of factory, not a complex constructor replacement

Comment: @Flater It seems all your concerns are addressed in the second implementation with FoodFactory as a separate class no? Sorry it just isn't very clear reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the main reason here is that you have applied a singleton pattern to your factory.

You can never have a different factory.

You can never mock the factory.

Comment: Hi, Can you please clarify a bit? Factory being a singleton is the main reason for what? And what do you mean by mock the factory?

Comment: reason to separate the factory class. and mock for tests